# SQL: When records are equal in two fields, select only one based on a third field

Tags: sql, ms-access

An SQL query: Suppose I have a table like

```
Student Module Mark OtherField
1       A      23   6
1       A      40   12
2       B      76   6
2       C      87   7
```

(the idea being that a student can resit a school module multiple times)
and I want to select only the highest score for each module, i.e. to output

```
Student Module Mark OtherField
1       A      40   12
2       B      76   6
2       C      87   7
```

That is: when two or more records are equal in the fields "Student" and "Module", how do I select the record with the highest "Mark" value?

Comment: MS Access/MS SQL Server/MySQL or everything?

Comment: So I suppose it's a general SQL question(?) Can't see how to do it in the GUI interface.

Comment: What if a student got his/her highest score twice? Should both values of `otherfield` be returned? Just one? If so, which one?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT
    t.Student,
    t.Module,
    MAX(t.Mark) AS Highest_Mark
FROM _your_student_table t
GROUP BY t.Student, t.Module
```

And if you need the OtherField (thx @Deepak Pawar for the hint), then:

```
SELECT
    x.Student,
    x.Module,
    x.Highest_Mark,
    y.OtherField
FROM
(
    SELECT
        t.Student,
        t.Module,
        MAX(t.Mark) AS Highest_Mark
    FROM _your_student_table_ t
    GROUP BY t.Student, t.Module
) x
INNER JOIN _your_student_table_ y
  ON x.Student = y.Student AND x.Module = y.Module AND x.Highest_Mark = y.Mark
```

Comment: this doesn't select otherfield(s).

Comment: Sorry, just saw, that it's for MS Access. In that case INNER JOIN is required. Otherwise it should work.

Comment: **Many thanks!**. This is perfect. Alas I'm too new for my +1 to count it seems, but please accept my thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  table.student,
  table.module,
  max(table.Mark) highestMark
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  table.module,
  table.student
```

Comment: But then how can I display OtherField?

Comment: you can include it in your select? @ASV

Comment: @edrodriguez I think, that is permitted in MySQL only; MS Access doesn't support that. You can select only those columns without aggregation which are in group by list.

Comment: isn't otherfield in the same table? @DeepakPawar

Comment: My interpretation of the question was that you wanted the highest mark per student per module.  I was not aware that you required OtherField in the select.  Apologies if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the syntax used in MS Access but it seems like you would just use something like this:

SELECT DISTINCT Student
       , Module
       , MAX(Mark)
       , Other Field
FROM   tbl_example
GROUP BY  Student
          , Module
          , Other Field

You get the idea....

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for, code-wise:

```
select
    student,
    module,
    mark,
    otherfield
from
    your_table as a
where
    mark = (select max(mark) from your_table as b where a.student = b.student and a.module = b.module);
```

However, you have a flaw in your logic. What happens if a student has a high score of, say, 85, and got that score twice? Should both values of `otherfield` be returned? Only one? Which one?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @John. As it happens the OtherField is basically unique so duplication isn't a problem. Thanks again!

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not worried about duplication of `otherfield`, I'm worried about duplication of `mark`... Is that guaranteed to be unique?